# Iterate through values in Objects in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I just want to iterate through the values in the object.The scenario is somethin like this!

```
roomsObject[socket.nickname]={"roomN":users[socket.nickname].roomName
                             ,"Clients":['A','B','C']};
```

where roomsObject is an object and i want to iterate through the clients.

```
 function updateRoomList(groupO,callback)
{
    roomParticularGroupList=[];
    for(var key in roomsObject)
    //this iterates through socket.nickname but i want to iterate through  roomsObject[socket.nickname].clients so that i get list of clients and send it back through callback  
    roomParticularGroupList.push(roomsObject[socket.nickname].clients);
    }
    console.log(roomParticularGroupList);
    callback(roomParticularGroupList);

}
```

Comment: Just do `callback(roomsObject[socket.nickname].Clients);`. If you just want to pass the elements of the array to the callback, you don't have to iterate over the array, you can pass it directly.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for (var key in roomsObject)
>     roomParticularGroupList.push(roomsObject[socket.nickname].clients);
> }
> ```

There is no `socket` with a `nickname` property here, you are enumerating the **`key`s** in the loop which you would have to use. Also, you've lowercased `clients`. It should be

```
for (var key in roomsObject)
    roomParticularGroupList.push(roomsObject[key].Clients);
}
```

Btw, there's hardly a reason to use a callback here. Simply `return roomParticularGroupList`.